# Using conditionals in form.io within a datagrid

Tags: javascript, json, formio

I am just starting to mess around with form.io and am a bit stuck.  I am trying to create some conditionals within each row of a datagrid.  E.g. If a radio button equaling "payIn" is selected then another field should appear in that same row.  I can do this statically by assigning the array number to the component's JSON but that obviously doesn't solve the problem of this working dynamically (this was just used to test the logic since it always points to the first row).  What could I do/use to make this logic work independently in each row within the datagrid?

```
{
"label": "Pay In Reason",
"widget": "choicesjs",
"hidden": true,
"tableView": true,
"data": {
  "values": [
    {
      "label": "Employee",
      "value": "employee"
    },
    {
      "label": "Bank",
      "value": "bank"
    }
  ],
  "json": "",
  "url": "",
  "resource": "",
  "custom": ""
},
"selectThreshold": 0.3,
"key": "payInReason",
"conditional": {
  "show": true,
  "when": "dataGrid[0].payInOut",
  "eq": "payIn"
},
"type": "select",
"indexeddb": {
  "filter": {}
},
"input": true,
"placeholder": "",
"prefix": "",
"customClass": "",
"suffix": "",
"multiple": false,
"defaultValue": null,
"protected": false,
"unique": false,
"persistent": true,
"clearOnHide": true,
"refreshOn": "",
"redrawOn": "",
"modalEdit": false,
"labelPosition": "top",
"description": "",
"errorLabel": "",
"tooltip": "",
"hideLabel": false,
"tabindex": "",
"disabled": false,
"autofocus": false,
"dbIndex": false,
"customDefaultValue": "",
"calculateValue": "",
"calculateServer": false,
"attributes": {},
"validateOn": "change",
"validate": {
  "required": false,
  "custom": "",
  "customPrivate": false,
  "strictDateValidation": false,
  "multiple": false,
  "unique": false
},
"overlay": {
  "style": "",
  "left": "",
  "top": "",
  "width": "",
  "height": ""
},
"allowCalculateOverride": false,
"encrypted": false,
"showCharCount": false,
"showWordCount": false,
"properties": {},
"allowMultipleMasks": false,
"clearOnRefresh": false,
"limit": 100,
"dataSrc": "values",
"valueProperty": "",
"lazyLoad": true,
"filter": "",
"searchEnabled": true,
"searchField": "",
"minSearch": 0,
"readOnlyValue": false,
"authenticate": false,
"template": "<span>{{ item.label }}</span>",
"selectFields": "",
"searchThreshold": 0.3,
"uniqueOptions": false,
"fuseOptions": {
  "include": "score",
  "threshold": 0.3
},
"customOptions": {},
"id": "eas39m"
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this works:  show = (row.component === 'value')